# Why aren't file globs subject to word splitting?

Tags: bash, wildcards

We are recommended that, in bash scripts, [we shouldn't parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

The webpage linked to above recommends code like:

```
# Good!
for f in *; do
    [[ -e $f ]] || continue
    ...
done
```

or to populate an array with filenames

```
myfiles=( ~/* )
```

But when I look at these examples, and knowing how bourne shells deal with unquoted strings in general, my sense is that if I used this code on filenames containing spaces the the glob would explode every - space separated - word on the files. e.g. If I have the following directory

```
$ ls -1  
a file I downloaded from the net.pdf
apple.sh
hello world.txt
```

and I run this

```
for file in *
    do printf "%s\n" "$file"
done
```

I'm expecting unquoted string behaviour. e.g.

```
a
file
I
downloaded
from
the
net.pdf
apple
hello
world
```

But what I get is the correct behaviour

```
a file I downloaded from the net.pdf
apple
hello world
```

similar for arrays

```
myfiles=( * )
declare -p myfiles
declare -a myfiles='([0]="a file I downloaded from the net.pdf" [1]="apple" [2]="hello world")'
```

My question is why is this?
Is it because glob expansion is done after word splitting? (so that these types of file operations produce correct output?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Filename expansion happens after word splitting

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and filename expansion.

Answer (score 1):

`[[ -e $f ]]` is a special case. `[[` is a reserved word; between `[[` and `]]` different rules are in effect. One of them is that no word splitting is performed.

Comment: ah right. but if `[ -e $f ]` was used, word splitting would be done, right?. Also I think that in the `[[ ]] ` context, the `*` character doesn't mean filenames from the current directory, it means "string pattern matching"? e.g. `if [[ $interface == wlp* ]]; then ...`

Comment: Right, `[` is part of a normal command line with the regular expansion rules.